# Ruby On Rails in MAMP mySQL Snow Leopard

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mamp

I'm trying to find step-by-step instructions to run Ruby on Rails on MAMP server and use MAMP's mySQL database.  I am on Snow Leopard also.  I have read Hivelogic's article about this but I really don't want to compile rails, ruby and mySQL.

Anyone have any suggestions

Comment: Unless you sure you won't use JRuby(jdbc connection), I don't recommend using ruby with MAMP, instead go the normal way with Apache and normal mysql installation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can suggest this tutorial for you;
[Using Ruby MySQL Gem with MAMP 1.8.x on Snow Leopard](http://www.beyondcoding.com/2009/11/10/using-ruby-mysql-gem-with-mamp-1-8-x-on-snow-leopard/)

Comment: Not to necro a post, but does anyone have an update for newer MAMP versions? They're now using cmake instead of their own configure script. Help?

Answer (score 8):

It is very simple, just edit your socket to MAMP's mysql socket in your rail's /config/database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: myproject_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: root
  host: localhost
  socket: /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: I had to install mysql separately with homebrew in order to be able to install the mysql2 gem, but after that this worked for me