# Using Ruby with MySQL installed via MAMP

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mamp

I'm a newbie. Here's 3 questions. Thank you.

1) If I have MySQL installed through MAMP on my Mac, can I use the MySQL in Ruby applications (i.e. if I install Ruby of course).

My understanding was that MAMP was a php/mysql package so I wouldn't know how to use Ruby with it. i.e. obviously no PHPMyAdmin for Ruby..

2) Should I do a separate install of MySQL to use with Ruby?

3) If I do need a separate install of MySQL, how do I let the computer know which I am trying to use if I make a database in the command line for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes you can, just point to the proper socket. And Ruby is already setup on Mac.
So you can have your PhpMyAdmin but I'd go for Sequel Pro.

2) Not mandatory, if you go this way, install brew first and set it up through it, it's really easy.

3) Apps will use sockets or the port you setup. In command line, it would depend on the Path you did setup.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I wonder if I give you some information, you could help some more. The other person who answered this question pointed me to the tutorial but I couldn't integrate it because my MAMP is already installed and the tutorial starts from a different spot (i.e. getting a tar file) http://bit.ly/1zNaR3    </br>  In response to your answer, I don't really know what "proper socket" means. MySQL is set up on port 8889 on my computer. Also when I enter "which mysql" it responds with "/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql"  Can you expand your answer to help some more? Thank you

Comment: Since I tried Sequel Pro, I've never looked back. It just simply beats phpMyAdmin, besides you can use it on your remote servers too, and save them as favourites, etc., etc.
Plus - it's free :)

Answer (score 2):

Using MAMP's MySQL from Ruby not the easiest approach, but I hate to have two of the same database server on one machine. Fortunately, this question has been asked and answered [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955366/ruby-on-rails-in-mamp-mysql-snow-leopard/1955404#1955404). Short version: yes, but there will be fiddly bits when you build your mysql gem.

A better solution in the long run might to be using another manager such as [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) or [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) to manage MySQL and Ruby. I stick with the stock PHP in OS X, but MacPorts has lots of nifty PHP stuff available for the curious.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I will look into MacPorts. Also, I looked at that answer that refers to the tutorial about using Ruby with MAMP, but it's way over my head, because it starts from a different place from where I'm currently at. If you have time and ability, please see my comment to the other answer on this page -- I would appreciate any suggestions. Cheers.